# Is my Piper broken?

Tags: fallout-4

I'm playing Fallout 4, and I maxed out Affection with Piper, and got her perk. She frequently repeats the last bit that lets me try to choose Romance, but always shoots it down. I have max Charisma (with additional gear boosts), pretty good Luck, and she adores me.

Is it just random, and eventually should work, or did I do something wrong, and it just wants to keep reminding me? I managed it with three other Followers, no problems, but Piper is being uniquely challenging, and I'm not sure if there is a reason. Is it Piper-specific?

Comment: Have you tried just talking to her? ;) I think before I romanced Piper I had selected pretty much every conversation option, asking about her sister and her past (e.g. did she tell you about how her dad died yet?)

Comment: What gender is your character? I looked over the wiki, and was surprised that no sexuality was listed for Piper. Do we know if all the companions you can romance are bisexual?

Comment: Hehe, Friendzoned in a videogame...

Answer (score 5):

**It's a [known bug](https://fallout.fandom.com/wiki/Piper_Wright#Bugs)**:

> Cannot romance Piper after she idolizes you (max affinity), even if player character's charisma is maxed. The key/button to select is there, but the option to romance is blank.

Piper seems to be the only one affected by this bug (let's hope it's not contagious).

**No fix to be found** there, however, nor in [this Steam thread](https://steamcommunity.com/app/377160/discussions/0/496881136914144990/), nor [this Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/fo4/comments/3sz8ab/cant_romance_piper_fo4/).
[This Steam thread](https://steamcommunity.com/app/377160/discussions/0/458604254460840585/) has **some comments that might prove useful**:

> - All the full affinity followers that I used the just friends option with will initiate a conversation with the option to romance while they are hanging out at Red Rocket. Try swapping companions and travel to wherever you send Piper.
> - You can trigger the conversation again, by lowering her approval to admire and then raise it again.